# How do you prove a sequence is monotonic?

Tags: calculus

I'm doing a math question, we're given two sequences $$\{a_i\}= \frac {i^2 +3}{i^2+2}$$ and $$\{b_i\}= \frac {1-\ln i}i$$ $\forall i\in \Bbb N,$ and we have to show if the sequences are monotonic or if they have a monotonic tail. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you give some more details? Do you know what monotonic means, for example? How far did you get?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If you can find a differentiable function $f$ defined on an interval $(a,\infty)$ such that $a_i = f(i)$, then the sequence $(a_i)$ is eventually monotonic if $f'$ is eventually nonzero (since that would make $f$ eventually increasing or eventually decreasing). If the interval $(a,\infty)$ contains all indices $i$, then the entire sequence is monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence $\{a_n\},n\in \Bbb N$ is monotonically increasing(or decreasing) if $a_{n+1}\ge(\text {or} \le) a_n$.

Now, notice that $$a_i=\frac {(i^2+2)+1}{i^2+2}\\\implies a_i=1+\frac 1{i^2+2}.$$

Now, show that $a_{i+1}\le a_i$.

Do the similar approach for the second one. You are provided $\ln i$ is an increasing sequence i.e. if $x_1\gt x_2$ then $\ln x_1\gt \ln x_2$.

Now, compare between $b_{i+1}$ and $b_i$.